# Sum and condition in oracle on update

Tags: oracle

am working on oracle database system , and i have to do the following:
All employees got a salary increase depending on their hiring dates as follows: (use one SQL statement)
10% salary increase if the employee was hired after 2001.
7% salary increase if the employee was hired between 1997 and 2000.
4% salary increase if the employee was hired before 1996.

and i used the following code

```
update employee set salary = case 
when hire_date>'1-1-2001' then salary=salary+salary*0.1
when hire_date between ('1-1-1997','1-1-2000') then salary=salary+salary*0.07
when hire_date < '1-1-1996' then salary=salary+salary*0.04
end
```

what is wrong with that ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
update stackoverflow_employee set salary = case 
when hire_date>'1-Jan-2001' then salary+salary*0.1
when hire_date between ('1-Jan-1997') AND ('1-Jan-2000') then salary+salary*0.07
when hire_date < '1-Jan-1996' then salary+salary*0.04
end
```

Points to remember:

1. Correct use of between operator Between X AND X
2. Date Format is 1-Jan-2012
3. While you are using SET salary = 'YOUR case statements', don't use salary= salary+salary*0.04 wihin the case.

Hope now your query is working :)

Comment: thank you very much , i was missing the between operator syntax , but the query is still not working
ORA-01407: cannot update ("EMPLOYEE"."SALARY") to NULL  weird error!!

Comment: try to use `case when ... when ... else salary end` to set salary to existing salary value

Comment: sorry but I wrote stackoverflow_employee as table name in first line, change it to employee or whatever is your table's actual name...

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
update employee
    set salary = (salary * (case when hire_date >= '2001-01-01' then 1.10
                                 when hire_date >= '1997-01-01' then 1.07
                                 else 1.04
                            end)
                 );
```

This fixes the obvious problems with the `salary =` and funky `between` clause.  It also moves into the `case` statement the logic that only needs to be there -- the amount of the increase.  Tt removes the `between` by taking advantage of the fact that `case` statements return the first match.  Finally, it uses ISO standard date formats.